# Cell size issue with Landsat data

Tags: resampling, cell-size

I have calculated a temperature map from Landsat Image. This map is correct but I the cells can be seen obviously. I have changed the cell size from 30m to match my other products which are 1m. I used resampling tool and the cell size is indeed changed when I check the source data but not in visualization. How can I make these apparent cell borders disappear?
[image: Attached is my map.]

Comment: If you resample one 30 m pixel into 1 m pixels you will get 30x30=900 identical pixels. That feels normal to me.

Comment: You don't magically create new data just by reducing the cell size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By resampling a 30m pixel at 1m, you're just breaking each Landsat pixel up into 900 smaller pixels, but they each have the same value as the large pixel. So the borders you see will not go away via resampling alone.

If you want to make the borders go away, you're going to have to smooth your resampled image. Not sure what programming language you're using, but all languages will have tools for convolution filters/smoothers. E.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html